# How to turn Bluetooth on and off with Python 3?

Tags: python, bluetooth

First timer here.  I'm new to RPi and Python in general.  I am making an RC car with my Pi, an Adafruit PCA9685, and an old OUYA bluetooth controller.

Everything works on my desk.  But, I want it to move around on the floor.  My next objective is to get the Pi running with no display or keyboard/mouse, and have the script run at boot.  I'm okay with figuring out all of that.

Where I'm stuck?
After boot, my Ouya controller won't connect unless I turn off the bluetooth, then turn it back on.  After which, I hit the "OUYA" button on the controller, it connects, all works as expected.

I've spent the better part of the past day or two searching the 'bluez' documentation, but I can't find a thing.

I have been reluctant to request from the forums, as I like to try to solve the problem myself, I have to ask, need to move on.

Thanks,

-Parsko

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "I turn off the bluetooth, then turn it back on"?  That might help prospective answerers to see where you are stuck a bit more clearly.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm using stock Raspbian on a Pi3.  I have loaded the Bluetooth manager, and I turn the bluetooth off then back on via that interface.  I have found if I go through 'bluetoothctl', and can get the same result.  My solution below seems to be working pretty well, resetting the bluetooth via the {hciconfig} commands.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution.  Bluetooth runs at startup, so it's there.  But, it needs to be reset before I can find it.  Once it's reset, I can connect easily.  Now, I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but this is the Python command  that solved this issue:

```
os.popen('sudo hciconfig hci0 reset')
```

If I run this after a reboot, I can just connect my OUYA controller as expected.

-Parsko